# SQL Error creating procedure: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "AS"

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, procedure

I'm entering the world of the procedure and I have this error that I have not found.

I do not need to add anything else and I do not know why he asks for "as".

Thanks

Error:

```
LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
2/22     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "AS" when expecting one of the
         following:
         in out <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>
         ... long double ref char time timestamp interval date binary
         national character nchar
```

Code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE INSERT_MOVIMIENTOS (
INSERTMOV_COD_BANCO  AS NUMBER(4),
INSERTMOV_COD_SUCUR  AS NUMBER(4),
INSERTMOV_NUM_CTA    AS NUMBER(10),
INSERTMOV_FECHA_MOV  AS DATE,
INSERTMOV_TIPO_MOV   AS CHAR(1),
INSERTMOV_IMPORTE    AS NUMBER(10)
)

DECLARE 
    sql_str VARCHAR2(500):='';

BEGIN
    sql_str:=sql_str||'INSERT INTO MOVIMIENTOS (';
    dbms_output.put_line(sql_str);
END;    
/

EXEC INSERT_MOVIMIENTOS (0, 0, 0, '2008-11-11', 'o', 0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no expert on Oracle, but according to this:  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6009.htm

You need to use `IN` instead of `AS` when declaring an input parameter.  With that in mind, I would try this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE INSERT_MOVIMIENTOS (
INSERTMOV_COD_BANCO  IN NUMBER(4),
INSERTMOV_COD_SUCUR  IN NUMBER(4),
INSERTMOV_NUM_CTA    IN NUMBER(10),
INSERTMOV_FECHA_MOV  IN DATE,
INSERTMOV_TIPO_MOV   IN CHAR(1),
INSERTMOV_IMPORTE    IN NUMBER(10)
)

DECLARE 
    sql_str VARCHAR2(500):='';

BEGIN
    sql_str:=sql_str||'INSERT INTO MOVIMIENTOS (';
    dbms_output.put_line(sql_str);
END;    
/

EXEC INSERT_MOVIMIENTOS (0, 0, 0, '2008-11-11', 'o', 0);
```